# Java DataOutputSream is working only once

Tags: java, sockets

I have a basic chat app. There are 3 classes: server, client and clientHandler. The problem is that server is able to read (using DataInputStream) only first time then it throws exceptions.

```
Hello. I have a basic chat app. There are 3 classes: server, client and clientHandler. The problem is that server is able to read (using DataInputStream) only first time then it throws exceptions.
```

Client.java:

```
package Client;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;


public class Client extends JFrame{

private JPanel contentPane;
private JTextField tf_input;
private static JTextArea ta_chat;
private JButton b_connect;


private static int portNumber = 2309;
private static String ip = null;
private JScrollPane scrollPane;
private JTextField tf_ip;


private Socket s = null;
private DataOutputStream dos = null;
private DataInputStream dis = null;
private JTextField tf_port;


private boolean connected = false;
private JLabel lblIp;
private JLabel lblPort;
private JLabel lblName;
private JTextField tf_name;
private JButton btnDc;


/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Client frame = new Client();
    frame.setVisible(true);


    System.out.println("Client is running!");


    // TODO Auto-generated method stub



    //Listening to server

    while(!frame.connected)
    {
        System.out.println("Waiting...!");
    }

    while(true)
    {
        System.out.println("Listening started!");
        String line = null;

        try {
            line = frame.dis.readUTF();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            ta_chat.append("reading from server failed\n");
            //System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " failed listening to server!\n");
        }

        if(line!=null)
            ta_chat.append(line.trim() + "\n");
    }
}

    //


/**
 * Create the frame.
 */
public Client() {
    setTitle("Client");
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 530, 458);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    setContentPane(contentPane);
    contentPane.setLayout(null);

    JButton b_send = new JButton("Send");
    b_send.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            if(!connected)
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You have to connect first!");
                return;
            }

            String message = tf_input.getText();

            try {
                ta_chat.append("writing UTF" + '\n');
                dos.writeUTF(message);
                ta_chat.append(ta_chat.getText().trim() + "writing UTF succeded" + '\n');
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                ta_chat.append(ta_chat.getText().trim() + "writing UTF failed" + '\n');
            }

            tf_input.setText(null);
        }
    });
    b_send.setBounds(375, 204, 89, 23);
    contentPane.add(b_send);

    tf_input = new JTextField();
    tf_input.setBounds(89, 205, 258, 20);
    contentPane.add(tf_input);
    tf_input.setColumns(10);

    scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
    scrollPane.setBounds(39, 11, 452, 175);
    contentPane.add(scrollPane);

    ta_chat = new JTextArea();
    scrollPane.setViewportView(ta_chat);
    ta_chat.setEditable(false);

    b_connect = new JButton("Connect");
    b_connect.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {

            connected = true;

            String ip = tf_ip.getText();
            String name = tf_name.getText();
            int portNumber = Integer.parseInt(tf_port.getText());

            try {
                s = new Socket(ip, portNumber);
                ta_chat.append("s=" + s + "\n");
            } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            try {
                dis = new DataInputStream(s.getInputStream());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
                ta_chat.append("dis init failed\n");
            }

            try {
                dos = new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
                System.out.println("DataOutputStraem object init failed!");
                ta_chat.append("dos init failed\n");
            }

            try
            {
                dos.writeUTF("/name " + name);
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                ta_chat.append("dos.writeUTF() failed \n");
            }
        }
    });
    b_connect.setBounds(89, 373, 89, 23);
    contentPane.add(b_connect);

    tf_ip = new JTextField();
    tf_ip.setBounds(83, 269, 123, 20);
    contentPane.add(tf_ip);
    tf_ip.setColumns(10);

    tf_port = new JTextField();
    tf_port.setColumns(10);
    tf_port.setBounds(83, 300, 123, 20);
    contentPane.add(tf_port);

    lblIp = new JLabel("IP:");
    lblIp.setBounds(39, 272, 46, 14);
    contentPane.add(lblIp);

    lblPort = new JLabel("Port");
    lblPort.setBounds(39, 303, 46, 14);
    contentPane.add(lblPort);

    lblName = new JLabel("Name:");
    lblName.setBounds(39, 335, 46, 14);
    contentPane.add(lblName);

    tf_name = new JTextField();
    tf_name.setColumns(10);
    tf_name.setBounds(83, 332, 123, 20);
    contentPane.add(tf_name);

    btnDc = new JButton("dc");
    btnDc.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            try {
                dis.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                dos.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            try {
                s.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
    btnDc.setBounds(290, 373, 89, 23);
    contentPane.add(btnDc);

}
```

}

Server.java:

```
package Server;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.URL;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class Server extends JFrame{

private JPanel contentPane;
private JTextField tf_input;

private static int portNumber = 2309;
private static JTextArea ta_ServerLog;
private JTextField tf_IP;
private JButton btnRefresh;
private JTextField textField;
private JLabel lblPort;
private static ServerSocket ss = null;

/**
 * Launch the application.
 */

public static void addTextToServerLog(String text)
{
    if(text.equals(null))
        return;
    else
        ta_ServerLog.setText(ta_ServerLog.getText().trim() + "\n" + text.trim());
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                Server frame = new Server();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {

            }
        }
    });


    try {
        ss = new ServerSocket(portNumber);
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    }


    while(true)
    {
        Socket s = null;
        try {
            s = ss.accept();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block

        }

        System.out.println("Creating new ClientListener!");
        new ClientHandler(s).start();
    }

}

/**
 * Create the frame.
 */
public Server() {
    setTitle("Server");
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 450, 377);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    setContentPane(contentPane);
    contentPane.setLayout(null);

    tf_input = new JTextField();
    tf_input.setBounds(125, 209, 109, 20);
    contentPane.add(tf_input);
    tf_input.setColumns(10);

    JButton b_send = new JButton("Send");
    b_send.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        }
    });
    b_send.setBounds(278, 209, 86, 20);
    contentPane.add(b_send);

    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
    scrollPane.setBounds(49, 26, 294, 136);
    contentPane.add(scrollPane);

    ta_ServerLog = new JTextArea();
    ta_ServerLog.setEditable(false);
    scrollPane.setViewportView(ta_ServerLog);

    JLabel lblYouAreHosting = new JLabel("Your IP:");
    lblYouAreHosting.setBounds(49, 277, 44, 14);
    contentPane.add(lblYouAreHosting);

    tf_IP = new JTextField();
    tf_IP.setEditable(false);
    tf_IP.setBounds(96, 274, 103, 20);
    contentPane.add(tf_IP);
    tf_IP.setColumns(10);

    btnRefresh = new JButton("Refresh IP");
    btnRefresh.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            tf_IP.setText(getIP());
        }
    });
    btnRefresh.setBounds(212, 273, 89, 23);
    contentPane.add(btnRefresh);

    textField = new JTextField();
    textField.setText(Integer.toString(portNumber));
    textField.setColumns(10);
    textField.setBounds(96, 305, 103, 20);
    contentPane.add(textField);

    lblPort = new JLabel("Port:");
    lblPort.setBounds(49, 308, 44, 14);
    contentPane.add(lblPort);

    JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("dc");
    btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            ss = null;
        }
    });
    btnNewButton.setBounds(10, 185, 51, 23);
    contentPane.add(btnNewButton);
}

private String getIP()
{
    URL site = null;
    try {
        site = new URL("http://checkip.amazonaws.com");
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    BufferedReader reader = null;
    try {
        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(site.openStream()));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try
    {
        return InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress().toString();
        //return reader.readLine();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {

    }

    return null;
}
```

}

ClientHandler.java:

```
package Server;
import java.awt.HeadlessException;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;


public class ClientHandler extends Thread{

private Socket clientSocket = null;
private DataInputStream dis = null;
private static ArrayList<Socket> users = null;


private String getIP()
{
    URL website = null;
    try {
        website = new URL("http://checkip.amazonaws.com");
    } catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    BufferedReader reader = null;
    try {
        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(website.openStream()));
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        return reader.readLine();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}


public ClientHandler(Socket clientSocket)
{

    this.clientSocket = clientSocket;

    if(users==null)
        users = new ArrayList<Socket>();

    try
    {
        users.add(clientSocket);
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        System.out.println("Adding client's socket to socket list failed!");
    }


    try
    {
        dis = new DataInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {

    }

    Server.addTextToServerLog("Trying to add a new client!");
    /*
    try {
        Thread.sleep(5000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    */
    Server.addTextToServerLog("Client added!"); 
}

public void tellEveryone(String message, String name)
{
    for (Socket socket : users) {
        Socket s = socket;

        try {
            DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
            dos.writeUTF(name + ":" + message);

            dos.close();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

public void disconnect()
{

}


// reciving messages from a specific client and send to everyone else
public void run()
{   
    while(true)
    {
        String line = null;

        try {
            System.out.println("Reading client input");

            Server.addTextToServerLog("-line-");
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            line = dis.readUTF();
            Server.addTextToServerLog("Line=" + line);

            if(line!=null)
            {

                if(line.startsWith("/name "))
                {
                    String name = line.replaceFirst("/name", "");
                    tellEveryone("joined room!", name);
                    Server.addTextToServerLog(name + "joined room!");
                }
                else
                {
                    tellEveryone(line, null);
                    Server.addTextToServerLog(line);
                }

            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        }   

    }
}
```

}

It throws exception from second try: (Client.java - this executes when the send button is pressed)

```
b_send.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            if(!connected)
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You have to connect first!");
                return;
            }

            String message = tf_input.getText();

            try {
                ta_chat.append("writing UTF" + '\n');
                dos.writeUTF(message);
                ta_chat.append(ta_chat.getText().trim() + "writing UTF succeded" + '\n');
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                ta_chat.append(ta_chat.getText().trim() + "writing UTF failed" + '\n');
            }

            tf_input.setText(null);
        }
    });
```

Server.java: (this part may be the relevant one)

```
while(true)
    {
        Socket s = null;
        try {
            s = ss.accept();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block

        }

        System.out.println("Creating new ClientListener!");
        new ClientHandler(s).start();
    }
```

ClientHandler.run():

```
public void run()
{   
    while(true)
    {
        String line = null;

        try {
            System.out.println("Reading client input");

            Server.addTextToServerLog("-line-");
            try {
                //Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            line = dis.readUTF();   // <----------- this works only 1st time  
            Server.addTextToServerLog("Line=" + line);

            if(line!=null)
            {

                if(line.startsWith("/name "))
                {
                    String name = line.replaceFirst("/name", "");
                    tellEveryone("joined room!", name);
                    Server.addTextToServerLog(name + "joined room!");
                }
                else
                {
                    tellEveryone(line, null);
                    Server.addTextToServerLog(line);
                }

            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        }   

    }
}
```

I have to say that the app worked a while ago, it had concurrency problems but it worked good enough. I have no back up.

Comment: Post the whole exception stacktrace

Answer (score 1):

At least part of the problem is in your client's `tellEveryone(2)` method:

```
DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
dos.writeUTF(name + ":" + message);
dos.close();
```

You're closing the stream every time you send a message. Because `dos` is created using the output stream of your client's `Socket` instance, it is closing the socket every time you call the `close()` method on `dos`. You should probably store `dos` as a member variable of your client class and only close it when you truly want to disconnect.

In addition, you should probably call `dos.flush()` each time you send a message to ensure that the entire message is written to the socket.  Sometimes, `OutputStream` implementations will cache data until a certain buffer size is reached, then flush the entire buffer to the underlying stream (in this case, the underlying stream is the socket itself). If you don't call `flush()`, there's a chance that some of the message won't get written to the socket due to buffering.

Make sure throughout your code that you're not closing any open sockets unless you truly want to disconnect, and this will likely fix your issue.

Comment: Yes. I removed:

Comment: I removed dos.close(). Now Server is receiving messages. But sometimes clients do not recieve back input from server. It seem to be random.

Comment: Even if that client do not receive messages from server he is able to send to server and it is able to replay it to other clients(that work). If a client do not receive a message once he never will. I mean some clients work but others just are not able to get server's output.

Comment: Are you now calling `dos.flush()` every time you are done sending a message?